# SQL WHERE condition for the most recent row

Tags: mysql

I know this should be super easy, but I just can't get my head around it.

I have a table with values like this:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | VALUE |
+----+-------+
|  1 |   100 |
|  2 |   200 |
|  3 |   100 |
|  4 |   300 |
+----+-------+
```

> I want to check if the most recent row (id 4) have the value 100.

I can't use LIMIT 1 or anything, and I'm sure I should use MAX() somehow, but I don't know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: what output do you want

Comment: can you clarify - you only want to output a row IF the value of the latest one is 100? ...or you want to output the latest row with the value 100?

Comment: "*I can't use LIMIT 1 or anything*"—why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * -- (or others fields you need)
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS A
WHERE A.ID = (SELECT MAX(B.ID)
              FROM YOUR_TABLE AS B) AND A.VALUE = 100 --(OR ELSE)
```